# Vuex store same as Database in real time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

sorry if this is a duplicate but couldn't find any opinions on this. Let's say I've an app with lots of forms split on different sections with every section having 2-3 questions. Every form does CRUD actions to my backend models.

For better understanding there are forms in which I need to fill in my sources of income, there are forms where I need to specify properties I own, etc.

According to these data my app do calculations etc. so I need to have a vuex store to distribute these data accross different components.

The problem is that I want to make the app and forms as fast as possible without any waiting for backend reponse, but I also want to send data after every section of form and I want to make sure that backend saved that data without any issue.

My question is - is it a good idea to set up actions like this:

```
async setIncome(context, payload) {
  const from = context.getters.getIncome;
  
  //merge payload into current state
  payload = Object.assign(from, payload);
  
  context.commit("setIncome", payload);
  
  try {
    await axios.patch(..., payload);
  } catch (e) {
    context.commit("setIncome", from);
    ...
  }
}
```

Also I would update whole store every x seconds according to database if some changes happens there

In theory this way I can keep my Vuex up to date with database and don't need to show loading screens when waiting for GET responses.

What do you think about this ?

Answer (score 1):

1. do not make API call in your VUEX ! your piece of code should do just one job and that is keeping the true data around your app.
2. I highly suggest separate your code (eg in plugin section in Nuxtjs) and update your store through actions in determined cycle.

Comment: Okay, I know what you mean by second one, but why is it a bad thing to make API calls inside Vuex module. Aren't actions meant for this ?

Comment: this is principle of  clean code. you must separate the concern. calling an API (how when and what to call in which also may change in future or in your new application) is not related to state management portion of your application. actions meant to be called outside of VUEX so you can track who changed it and when it changed

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I will keep that in mind. But anyway, do you think that changing state earlier than obtaining response from API is okay ? As I said I want to keep my app as fast as possible without awaiting every API promise.